# getting elemints out of simpleXML Array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am trying to get elements out of a simpleXML array and for some reason I am unable to call them.

Here is the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [NameChangeIndicator] => N
            [NameChangeDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [PreviousName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [Score] => 53
            [NumberOfSubs] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [NumberOfJU] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [DateLastJU] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [NumberActPrincipals] => 1
            [NumberActPrincipalsJU] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LastestBankCode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LastestBankCodeDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [NumberRDs] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LiqIndicator] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [TotEnqLast12Mth] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [TotEnqLast3Mth] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsNoOfReferences] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsHighMthPurchases] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsHighMthPurchasesTermGiven] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsHighMthPurchasesTermTaken] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsLowMthPurchases] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsLowMthPurchasesTermGiven] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefsLowMthPurchasesTermTaken] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [KissNoOfSuppliers] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [KissNoOfODSuppliers] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [KissAmountOS] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [KissAmountOD] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [KissPercntage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LatestBankCodeDesc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [HoldingCmpName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So I am doing the following call to get the array.

```
$new_str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
$new_str = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','',$new_str);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($new_str);
$dom = new SimpleXMLElement($new_str);
$xml_array = $dom->xpath("//*[name()='ReportSummary']");
echo "{$xml_array[0]['Score']}";
```

But I am unable to pull the object out of the Array. I am not sure if the array 
is being correctly sent back to me due to the fact that if I don't decode the string I don't get a array back. The weird thing is that in the array I keep on seeing "SimpleXMLElement Object" and I am not sure if that is correct.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the output of: `var_dump($str);` and update your question with it (not in the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dump output says, SimpleXML is a type of object, not a way of creating arrays.

These two lines are different ways of writing the same thing, you only need one of them; in either case you end up with a `SimpleXMLElement` object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($new_str);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($new_str);
```

The outer array you are seeing is to hold the results of the XPath query, since they can come from anywhere in the XML tree. It is an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects.

For how to access data using SimpleXML, see [the basic usage page in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

In your case, `Score` is an element of the document, so needs to be accessed with the `$node->property` syntax.

Here's a tidied up version of your code:

```
$new_str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
// Are you sure the next line is necessary? That looks like a valid XML opening to me.
$new_str = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','',$new_str);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($new_str);

// I think this simpler XPath expression means the same as yours, but I might be wrong
$xpath_results = $xml->xpath('//ReportSummary');

// Beware that the XPath could return no matches, in which case the following 
// would give an error. Best to check count($xpath_results) > 0 first.
echo $xpath_results[0]->Score;
```

Answer (score 0):

To IMSoP: thanks for the help but I had to modify it a bit:

```
$dom = new SimpleXMLElement($new_str);
$xml_array = $dom->xpath("//*[name()='ReportSummary']");
echo $xml_array[0]->Score;
```

And from that I got the correct result, thanks a lot!